# *nix hosting - redirect download to homepage if referrer doesn't match

Tags: apache, unix, redirect, referrer

I have a software package placed in the root directory of my website. I'd like all visitors which come from other websites to see the homepage first, before they download. How can I do that without using a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache's mod_rewrite can do this. It can test 'HTTP_REFERER' variable and create a redirect.

Example from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

> Description:
>
> Assume we have under
>   http://www.quux-corp.de/~quux/ some
>   pages with inlined GIF graphics. These
>   graphics are nice, so others directly
>   incorporate them via hyperlinks to
>   their pages. We don't like this
>   practice because it adds useless
>   traffic to our server. Solution:
>
> While we cannot 100% protect the
>   images from inclusion, we can at least
>   restrict the cases where the browser
>   sends a HTTP Referer header.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.quux-corp.de/~quux/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.gif$        -                                    [F]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}         !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}         !.*/foo-with-gif\.html$
RewriteRule ^inlined-in-foo\.gif$   -                        [F]
```

Other variant http://articles.sitepoint.com/print/apache-mod_rewrite-examples

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example\.com/.*$ [NC]  
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ http://www.example.com/hotlinked.gif [R=301,L]
```

First line checks if referer is empty. second - if it is not your domain.
Third will redirect "bad queries" to "hotlinked.gif"

Comment: Worked great for http://uberstaller.com :

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?uberstaller\.com/.*$ [NC]  
RewriteRule \.(exe|zip)$ http://uberstaller.com/download_uberstaller.html [R=301,L]

I should also mention uploading these instructions as ".htaccess".

Thanks!